# Making Generics in Shapeless 2.0.0

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'd like to do the following with Shapeless 2.0.0:

```
  def freeze[T]( o:T ) = {
   val gen = Generic[T]
   gen.to(o)
  }
```

This gives me an error saying that T is not a case class or trait.  Is there any way to do this?
(I can do val gen = Generic[Foo].  That's fine, but what if I need to be able to build a Generic from something not known at compile-time?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really anything interesting you can do with a plain old `T`—most operations in Shapeless require you to provide some kind of evidence about the type in the form of implicit parameters, like this:

```
import shapeless.Generic

def freeze[T](o: T)(implicit gen: Generic[T]) = {
  gen.to(o)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> freeze(Foo(10))
res0: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil] = 10 :: HNil
```

The only time `Generic[T]` will work as a value is when the compiler knows concretely what `T` is.